# Return some coefficient depending on input value

Tags: python, math

I have some value `z = [20, 21.2, 23, 24.4, ..., 92.8, 100]`, and I have `min_coef = 0, max_coef = 0.6`

Can someone help me please to create function that will input my `z` value and return some `coef` for input z value?

I suppose it should look something like this:

```
def foo(min_z, max_z, min_coef, max_coef, my_z):
    ...
    return coef
```

Example 1

```
my_z = 20
my_coef = foo(min(z), max(z), min_coef, max_coef, my_z)
# my_coef = 0.0 (or 0.00001)
```

Example 2

```
my_z = 60
my_coef = foo(min(z), max(z), min_coef, max_coef, my_z)
# my_coef = 0.3
```

Example 3

```
my_z = 100
my_coef = foo(min(z), max(z), min_coef, max_coef, my_z)
# my_coef = 0.6
```

And especially, I would be grateful if someone could tell me, what type of math it is, so I can study about it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(min_coef, max_coef, my_z):
    min_val = min(my_z)
    max_val = max(my_z)
    z_range = max_val - min_val
    coef_range = max_coef - min_coef
    scale = coef_range / z_range
    
    result = []
    for i in range(len(my_z)):
        result.append((my_z[i] - min_val) * scale + min_coef)
    return result
```

The math is basic algebra.

Edit: I just realized you wanted the function to take a number rather than a list, so I'll include the code for that as well for completeness.

```
def foo(min_coef, max_coef, min_z, max_z, my_z):
    z_range = max_z - min_z
    coef_range = max_coef - min_coef
    scale = coef_range / z_range
    return (my_z - min_z) * scale + min_coef
```